# How to work with large data arrays (over 10MiB) effectively in Go?

Tags: go, buffer

I am working with go to download files from one server and after manipulating the files sending it to another server.

The files size can vary from 1MB to 200MB.

Currently, my code is pretty simple, I am using http.Client and bytes.Buffer . 
It takes lot of time to handle does big files (the 100MB to 200MB) which there is a lot of them.

After a quick profiling, I see that most of the time I do bytes.(*Buffer).grow, 
How can I create big buffers for example for 16MB?

What can I do in order to improve my efficiency of the code? General tips for handling with large http requests?

**Edit**

I will explain, exactly what I am trying to do.
I have couchdb documents (with attachments) that I am trying to copy to another couchdb instance.
The couchdb documents size can be from 30MB to 200MB, copying tiny (2 - 10MB) couchdb documents - is really fast.

But sending the document over the wire is really slow.
I am currently, trying to profile, and try to use @Evan answer to see what is my problem.

Comment: Could you post some code? It's much easier to see your problem if we have some insight in how you perform the task you perform. Right now your task is extremely vague.

Comment: My code is pretty ugly, I will write a little description of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the description for `bytes.NewBuffer`: http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer

Sounds like you can create a 16MB byte slice and use it to initialize the buffer.

Comment: This fixed my problem, after creating the right size of a buffer it improved io.Copy alot

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the fact your program has no need to *keep* the data in memory if all it needs to do is to *copy* it.

Now the strong feature of Go's standard library is sensible uses of interfaces: `http.Response`'s `Body` member is something implementing the `io.ReadCloser` interface, and that satisfies the type of the `body` argument of the `http.Client`'s `Post` method.

So you could roll like this:

1. Perform a request for the document—you'll get an instance of `http.Response` back, which has the `Body` member of type `io.readCloser`.

   Note that at this point you haven't actually started receiving the body from the "source" server because to do that you'll have to drain the `io.ReadCloser` of `Body`.
2. Initiate another (supposedly `POST`) request to *send* the data, and when making the request supply it that `Body` member obtained in the first step.

   Once this request is done *piping* your data, call `Close()` on that `Body` member.

Something like this:

```
import "net/http"

func Pipe(from, to string) (err error) {
    src, err := http.Get(from)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    dst, err := http.Post(to, myPostType, src.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    // Now read and then Close() the dst.Body member.
}
```

In this code, `http.Post` [will read from `src.Body` and then `Close()` it itself](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Post).

You *might* add `bytes.Buffer` into the mix in hope to reduce the amount of syscalls performed but don't do that unless the plain method does not work.

Comment: The one problem is - I don't just GET a body and send it away, I change json and the multiparts.

Comment: @Yosi, but you yourself said "I have couchdb documents (with attachments) that I am trying to *copy* to another couchdb instance", right? (Emphasis mine.) So next time please try to be more precise to not waste other people's time.

Answer (score 1):

As @Evan already pointed out: you can choose an initial buffer size when creating a new buffer.

Since allocation of buffers is so expensive (this is why your `grow` calls take so long; they re-allocate if the size does not fit anymore), picking the right buffer size is key. Picking the right strategy for buffer allocation depends on a lot of factors. You might choose your own method of growing buffers depending on your application profile.

You should also consider recycling your buffers to prevent heap fragmentation: http://blog.cloudflare.com/recycling-memory-buffers-in-go